# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' with PyXL

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working with PyXL and at some point my file crashed and I had to start anew.
What was perfectly working stopped doing so. Here's the problem.

```
def val(x, y):
    return sheet_obj.cell(row=x, column=y).value
path = (r"C:\Users\tashkpa\Desktop\Python\python and excel.xlsx")
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
wb_obj['Sheet1']['CE1'].value='Dk1'

for m in range(2,2161):
    sheet_obj.cell(row = m, column = 83).value = val(m,5)+val(m,8)
```

gets this thrown at me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tashkpa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/as.py", line 28, in <module>
    sheet_obj.cell(row = m, column = 83).value = int(val(m,5)+val(m,8))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

What am I doing wrong? The Excel file I'm working with contains bunch of numerical data (floats), and values are there. It worked perfectly well for some time, then the previous Excel file got corrupted because I tried to write two interdependent fns in one cell or something like this, so I had to start anew. The xls should not be an issue.

Comment: You can't add `None` to anything not even itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with OpenPyXL -- I've just now skimmed through the docs, but can't guarantee that I'm not missing the mark here:

I'm guessing that for some row between 2 and 2,161 in `C:\Users\tashkpa\Desktop\Python\python and excel.xlsx`, for columns 5 and 8, there exists two blank values, which are represented as `None` by OpenPyXL.  Python can't figure out how to add `None` to anything, as it isn't a number, and Python doesn't have any appreciation for poetic interpretation.

If I wanted to debug this further, and I were avoiding using a debugger because "holy for-loop Batman, that'll take forever", I might put a print statement as the first line of the for loop:

```py
for m in range(2,2161):
    print(f"Reading row {m}:  {val(m,5)=} and {val(m,8)=}")
    sheet_obj.cell(row = m, column = 83).value = val(m,5)+val(m,8)
```

From there at least you'll be able to tell at which line Python is going into conniptions.

If there are sporadic blank rows that you want to handle without Python balking, maybe:

```py
for m in range(2,2161):
    if val(m,5) is None or val(m, 8) is None:
        print(f"Looks like row {m} had one or more blank values {val(m,5)=}, or {val(m,8)=}")
        continue
    sheet_obj.cell(row = m, column = 83).value = val(m,5)+val(m,8)
```

Comment: thanks for nudging me in the right direction. My range was too wide (I forgot that I had removed some data previously), and there were empty cells from the row 1418 onward. Once I corrected this, everything worked well. Thanks!